# Lots of trouble with group combat in The Witcher 1

Tags: the-witcher

I'm playing The Witcher 1 (Enhanced Edition, if that makes a difference), and I'm having a *ton* of trouble with the combat. The trouble started in chapter 1 when fighting

> the beast,

and now I'm in chapter 2 attempting to get through the part where

> you speak with the PI and are ambushed around the city when leaving at midnight.

These fights all involve multiple people, and I die *incredibly* quickly whenever fighting more than one person/enemy at once. I've only been able to make it this far by cheating the system--running far enough away so someone leashes back and I only have to fight one person, things like that. I cannot for the life of me figure out how to properly fight more than one person at a time.

- I'm trying all three styles. Group style does almost no damage to anyone involved, same with fast, and none of the opponents at the moment require the strong style.
- I found a Sword of the Order (only -10% damage) which I'm using in place of the standard Temerian steel sword (-20% damage).
- I do try to mix in my signs, but they don't really have much effect. Aard usually does literally nothing.

Any advice for group combat in TW1 would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Remember, take it slow. You have to left-click only when necessary to chain attacks, and don't forget you can also parry (when not using signs).

Comment: So did you get it?

Answer (score 1):

Fighting [the Beast](http://witcher.wikia.com/wiki/Hellhound) in Chapter 1 is challenging, because your combat styles are not yet well-developed. Some advice are very specific to the Beast fight, including:

- meditating near the Abigail fire until 9 pm, *then* drinking your potions, applying oils and visiting places of power. When the Beast cutscene triggers, in-game time jumps to midnight, and you don't want to lose your buffs.
- rushing straight to the Beast and stunning it with Aard. If done right, this may give you a great head start in the fight.

Fighting multiple human enemies in Chapter 2 should be easy with Group Steel talents allocated. The group style is specifically designed to protect you from multiple enemies attacking you at the same time. If you run into trouble, check that:

- your Group Steel talents are allocated
- you are [chaining the attacks correctly](http://witcher.wikia.com/wiki/Combat_in_The_Witcher) and not just clicking as fast as possible
- you have a decent steel sword equipped and selected for the fight (silver swords will do nought to human enemies)

[Oils](http://witcher.wikia.com/wiki/The_Witcher_oils) increase the damage you deal with your swords, which can also help you to get through fights.